# Closure of sets (specifically regarding the notation)

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, notation

I'm new to sets and the notation is somewhat confusing to me.  I just want to see if what I'm doing makes sense.

For the following sets I need determine if it is open, closed, or neither.  I also need to state the closure (this is the part where I'm unsure about the notation).

$(-\infty, -1)$, closed, $cl\;S=(-\infty,-1]\cup\{-1\}$

Can I combine interval notation with set builder notation connected with union?

$\{\frac{4}{n}:n \in \mathbb N\}$, neither, $cl\;S=\{\frac{4}{n}:n\in \mathbb N\}\cup \{0\}$

$\{x:x^2 \gt 0\}$, open, $cl\;S=(0,\infty)\cup\{0\}$

$\mathbb Q$, neither, $cl\;S=$???

Comment: That's perfectly fine. Although in your first example, the union is redundant. The closure of $(-\infty, -1)$ is the half-closed interval $(-\infty, -1]$ which is the same as $(-\infty, -1) \cup \{-1\}$. However $(\infty, -1] \cup \{-1\} = (-\infty, -1]$ since $-1$ is in the set.  You can also rewrite your third example as $[0,\infty)$ which is the same as $(0,\infty) \cup \{0\}$.

Comment: @PhilipHoskins awesome!  What about the last one, I don't know what the closure of that would be since it doesn't have a boundary?

Comment: And yeah closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{R}$ as any irrational number will belong to closure as any open ball around irrational numbers contain infinitely many rationals. Is it clear?

Comment: @free_mind: Between any two real numbers is a rational number (see: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Between_two_Real_Numbers_exists_Rational_Number). From this you can deduce that $\operatorname{cl}(\mathbb{Q}) = \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to say a few things here...are you studying analysis or topology?
If you are studying analysis then you can talk about closure which directly means closure in standard topology but if you are studying topology you need to ask first is it standard topology or discrete topology or lower limit topology or K topology and stuff like that. Assuming you are doing analysis :

Ok so now, you must know that $(-\infty,-1]=(-\infty,-1)\cup\{-1\}$

And closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{R}$ in standard topology. (As any open ball(defined in standard topology) around any irrational number contains infinitely many rationals)

Rest of them are ok.

Comment: The class is Concepts of Real Analysis, but we are covering some topology

Answer (score 1):

Writing $(-\infty,-1]\cup\{-1\}$ is redundant since $-1\in(-\infty,-1]$.

When you write cl in LaTeX, write \operatorname{cl} instead; it will give it the right styling.

Lastly, $\operatorname{cl}\mathbb{Q}=\mathbb{R}$, since each sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$ converges to a real number and any real number can be written as a convergent sequence of rationals.

Comment: I figured the closure of $\mathbb Q$ would be $\mathbb R$, but I wasn't entirely sure.

Comment: @free_mind. The denseness of Q in R follows from the def'n of R.